# Invalid back reference using grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

So I am trying to find 6-letter words that consist of one character repeated three times followed by another character repeated three times. For example `aaabbb` or `oookkk`.

I am trying:

```
grep -E "[a-z]\1{3}\S[a-z]\1{3}" filename
```

First, is the regex correct? Second why am I getting `grep: Invalid back reference`?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you need to match. Your regex is not correct so I can't understand what you are after. Are you looking for words that consist of 3 repetitions of one character and then three repetitions of another? Or do you also want to match `aaabbbfoobar`? What about `aaaabbb`? Ideally, show us some example input and your desired output.

Comment: A backreference should refer to something, and you haven't specified what that something is. Usually you group an expression using parentheses to do so. For example: `grep -E '([a-z]{2})([0-9]{2})\2\1'` would match `aa9999aa`.

Comment: @terdon Are you looking for words that consist of 3 repetitions of one character and then three repetitions of another? Yes.
Or do you also want to match aaabbbfoobar? No.
Only words like `oookkk` (no longer than 6 characters) NOT words containing `oookkk` like `oookkkfoobar`

Comment: @HighlightsFactory OK, in that case use the `grep -w` example I gave in my answer.

Comment: One more thing, do you also want to match `aaaaaa` or do you need at least two different characters? Please consider giving us example input and desired output.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it's not correct. I have no idea what the `\1{3}` is supposed to be but that's what is causing you problems. If you want to find lines that contain three repeated characters followed by three other repeated characters, you can use this:

```
grep -E '([a-z])\1{2}([a-z])\2{2}'
```

The `\1` refers to the first *captured* group. You can capture groups by using parentheses. Then, `\1` is the 1st such group and `\2` is the second and so on. Since you had no captured groups, `grep` was complaining about an invalid reference since it had nothing to refer to. So, in the regex above, the parentheses are capturing the two groups. Then, you want `{2}` and not `{3}` since the initial match is also counted.

You don't specify whether you need the match to be a word or whether you also want to match within words. If you want the entire word to match (and exclude things like `aaaabbb`, use this instead:

```
grep -wE '([a-z])\1{2}([a-z])\2{2}'
```

To print only the matched portion of the line (the word) and not the entire line, use (GNU grep only):

```
grep -owE '([a-z])\1{2}([a-z])\2{2}'
```